# MySQL - TimeStamp as Byte array with ASP.NET CORE 2

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I insert TimeStamp value as Byte array into MySQL 5.6.27 with ASP.NET CORE 2 with Dapper 1.50.5?

I'm using below code to do so,

```
   var value = BitConverter.GetBytes(Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss")).Ticks);
```

However the above code gives me error while insert

> Incorrect datetime value: '\x00d\xF9\x99\xB8\x02\xD6\x08'

Model Class has field as,

```
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

MySql Table column property as,

```
Column: RowVersion
Definition:RowVersion Timestamp
```

How can I insert this value?

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" minutes should be lowe case mm. But i dont know if that will fix it

Comment: @Budyn, had tried this but getting same error.

Comment: Are you porting this code from MS-SQL (TSQL)? MySql `timestamp` is not a binary column type; [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html). Also, you really shouldn't be inserting into a `timestamp` column, they are intended to be managed by the server for optimistic concurrency checks [other doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html).

Comment: Assuming you've configured the byte[] property as a `TimeStamp` in EF parlance (which it looks like you have), then the value is generated on insert; you should *not* be setting a value manually.

Comment: @MarcL & Chris Pratt - Thanks for suggestion. I have changed the approach now and moving with https://sverrehundeide.wordpress.com/2015/05/22/optimistic-concurrency-with-mysql-and-entity-framework/